# Error Loading ssis package in C# using VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-applications, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I coded Web application in which I face error on loading package

```
The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
```

Developed pacakage in VS2013 SSDT, Web application in VS2013, Using Sql Server 2012 Developer Edition

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the event log?
 It can have additional information other than the error message.
 
This can happen due to many reasons. 
1)Are you using any third party components? If they are of different versions on the developer and server machines then this message can appear.
2) If the development server is 32bit and deployment server is 64bit or vice-versa.
There can be other reasons as well. Can you run the package independently (either through DTExec or in Visual Studio).

Comment: I received same error msg in event log too.. didnt use 3rd party components.. i ruuning  localhost ..i get error while debug the program

Comment: Does the package run successfully independently and not through web application?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1006218/Problem-installing-ispac-in-SQL-Server

http://www.resolvinghere.com/sm/loading-ssis-packages-0xc0011008.shtml           as per on these link answers cannot load vs 2013 ssis package on sql server 2012 .. are we have option to find solution

Comment: Yes while independently the package run successfully..  when its debug from web application this erro occurs